# Function returning 'None' instead of term

Tags: python, web2py

I am trying to pass a value from a form to a function, process it, and then call the function in another function. Basically, the user submits a search term. It is passed to a function called `process` which returns the now processed term as a dictionary. In the `results` function, the term is parsed to a search engine API and the results are returned in a HTML or JSON format. The function `process` is returning none instead of the processed term however. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? This is being done in web2py so some of the code may look odd, but I think the problem is a python one, rather than a web2py

```
import urllib2

def index():
    form = FORM('',
            INPUT(_name='query', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            INPUT(_type='submit'))
    if form.process().accepted:
        redirect(URL('results'))
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'form has errors'
    else:
        response.flash = 'please fill the form'
    return dict(form=form)

def __process():
    term=request.vars.query
    #do some processing
    return dict(term=term)

def results():
    import urllib2
    address = "http://www.blekko.com/?q=%(term)s+/json&auth=<mykey>" % __process()

    results = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()

    return dict(results=results)
```

Comment: Could `term` be an empty list?

Comment: @Junuxx it shouldn't be. By saying term=request.vars.query, it assigns the value in the 'query' form to the variable term. Term should be a dictionary value. I'm sure it's something to do with the __process function though

Comment: try `print`ing `term` just before the return line, but after the processing?

Comment: I don't know how to do this with the web2py interface. There's nowhere for it to print to!

Comment: @adohertyd: You haven't shown any concrete evidence that `__process` is returning None.  Why do you think it is?  Also: get rid of the double underscore names, they are silly.

Comment: @adohertyd: then use the logging module.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I know it is returning none because my app outputs the json results with the word None appended to each URL. And I'm using the double underscore naming convention because otherwise returning a dict in web2py requires a corresponding view page which I don't need.

Comment: @adohertyd: with just the code you've given us, there's no way to debug the problem.  Your `__process` function either returns a dict with one key, or it raises an exception.  There is no way for it to return None.  Perhaps your real code has a way to do it, but the summary you've posted does not.  Show your real code.

Comment: @NedBatchelder that is all of the code I have except for the HTML pages which do nothing. Wooble; sorry I'm really new to web2py so don't know how to use the logging module just yet. Just thought that my problem might be evident to more experienced programmers that's all. Will try to find a way to debug it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's web2py issue.
When you redirect() in web2py, request.vars are not passed on to the new page. *session vars do though.*

Try printing request.vars inside the form.process().accepted and then again in the __process().

Instead, do the processing all inside the index() and then return the result dict to index view. Then you can redirect or open a new window pass the data along.
Or if you'd rather keep the things way they are, store it in the session for it to be accessible from __process().

Comment: Thanks! But just say I remove the `__process` function and just call the dict term directly after the URL: `"http://www.blekko.com/?q=%(term)s+/json&auth=<mykey>" % dict=(term=request.vars.query)` this works. Why so?

Comment: No, that will not work. Once you redirect from the index() function, you start a whole new request and therefore lose any request.vars. request.vars will be empty when the request for the results() function comes in.

Comment: @Anthony added `session.term=request.vars.query` into the `form.accepted` function and my code works now. Thanks for the clarification guys